# Android用Mobile Vision Text API OCR　で単数字の認識方法を教えてください。

Tags: android, api

お世話になっております。
Android用Mobile Vision Text API OCR　で単数字の認識方法を教えてください。

具体的には以下のサンプルコードで下の例のような単数字列を認識できる方法を模索しています。
サンプルコード：https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#1

例１
　
1
2
3
4

※上のような数字列には反応してくれません。
　ただし、以下のような数字には反応します。

例２
10
20
30
40

２桁以上の数字から反応してくれるようです。
理想の動作として、例１で全ての数字を囲んで一回で読み込めればと考えております。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考：2017年5月から11月の間に投稿された同様の内容のQ&Aをいくつか見つけましたが、いずれも「どうも現状できないらしい」という結論で終わっているようでした： [Read only 1 char](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/196) ／ [Mobile Vision API (TEXT) not detecting single numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44100196/5989200) ／ [How to read a single character with Google OCR vision-samples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47083928/5989200)

Comment: nekketsuuu様
お答えいただきありがとうございます。
やはり、不可能な状態だったのですね。
私の理解不足の可能性に期待していたのですが…
残念です。
それでも教えていただけたおかげで今後の方針が決められます。
ありがとうございました。